# Will the component tags be re-utilized for Lightning Web Components?

Tags: discussion

As of today, on SFSE, there already exists tags viz., `lightning-button`, `lightning:tab`, etc. to name a few which are currently used in context of Lightning Components.

Now that Lightning Web Components will have the component names viz., `lightning-button`, `lightning-tab`, etc. is the plan to use these tags in context for both Lightning Components and Lightning Web Components?

With `lightning-web-components` already in place now, will that be sufficient enough to differentiate the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no significant difference between the two components (because they are all LWC under-the-hood anyways). That aside, we now have [lightning-aura-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-aura-components) and [lightning-web-components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-web-components), so this should definitely already be context sensitive. I see no reason to introduce a duplicate version of each, unless we start discovering major differences between the two (e.g. a bug that exists in LWC but not LAC).

I don't think this will happen, but we should monitor the situation for at least 3 months and come up with a decision then. I'm not sure we'll have an easy migration path anyways, because we can't have `lightning:button` versus `lightning-button` for these tags. I'm not sure these tags belong at all (but they already exist, so what's done is done). Normally, tags should be over rather major categories (e.g. soap-api or lightning-web-components); since specific tags tend to not get used and simply provide bloat.

Comment: On part of the tags, I would say it was foresightedness while creating those :)